# Copying values in columns from one worksheet to the rows of another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one worksheet which stores data in a horizontal format as this is better layout for planning however I need to present the same data in a vertical format to aid others calculating fatigue.

How can I automate this with formula?  In the attached you can see how it is presented in worksheet 1 and how I need to present it in worksheet 2.

Your help and advice is greatly appreciated thank you :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pelQHHA_ymhLo3bqyRq3uuVHWfEDY1rX/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105880391007158608016&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please don't share files via a link. Instead post some sample data and desired output within your question. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). As an answer to your question look into `TRANSPOSE`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with just *one* formula. I think we need multiple formula's to start constructing the vertical version of your horizontal overview.